# How to plot other dimensions in PCA plot using DISTATIS

Tags: r, pca, dimensions, eigenvalue, covariance-matrix

I'm wondering how to find the correct eigen values and % of explain variances of my distatis plot. I'm using the package DistatisR.

I have the following code now:

```
DistanceCube <- DistanceFromSort(*owndata*)
testDistatis <- distatis(DistanceCube)
summary(testDistatis)

# 4.1 Get the bootstrap factor scores (with default 1000 iterations)
BootF <- BootFactorScores(testDistatis$res4Splus$PartialF)
# 4.2 Get the boostrap from full bootstrap (default niter = 1000)
F_fullBoot <- BootFromCompromise(DistanceCube,niter=1000)

# creat graphic
rv.graph.out <- GraphDistatisRv(testDistatis$res4Cmat$G)
compromise.graph.out <- GraphDistatisCompromise(testDistatis$res4Splus$F)
partial.scores.graph.out <- GraphDistatisPartial(testDistatis$res4Splus$F,testDistatis$res4Splus$PartialF)
boot.graph.out.ell <- GraphDistatisBoot(testDistatis$res4Splus$F,BootF)
```

I don't know if it's correct to do the following afterwards to find the eigen values and % of explained variance.

```
# print eigenvalues and % of expl. variance. 
summary(prcomp(testDistatis$res4Splus$F))
```

Here is an article which shows the information I need in the graph: 
[example pictures showing eigenvalues and % of explained variances in graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVuY.png)

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950329310000972

Secondly, I also need to know how I can plot `dim2` vs `dim3` besides just `dim1` and `dim2`. While using the output from the distatis. I hope someone can help me.